# smbclient does not work on RHEL 8.7: "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: rhel, smbclient

```
smbclient //10.206.241.204/C$ -U administrator -d 3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
added interface ens192 ip=10.206.241.215 bcast=10.206.241.255 netmask=255.255.254.0
Password for [SAMBA\administrator]:
Client started (version 4.16.4).
Connecting to 10.206.241.204 at port 445
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'ncalrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
Cannot do GSE to an IP address
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

All VMs in question are using x86/x64 CPU architecture, 64-bit OSes. I just mention this because apparently having mixed CPU architecture in the environment can cause this (not applicable in my case).

I have updated / uninstalled / reinstalled the SMB client - nothing changes. Can this be fixed?

I am able to connect to SMB servers (Windows VMs) with other server (Ubuntu, PhotonOS, Windows), just not this RHEL 8.7 server.

`journalctl | grep smbclient`

```
Mar 01 14:30:45 RHEL-8-Salt-Master systemd-coredump[4025428]: Process 4025418 (smbclient) of user 0 dumped core.
Mar 01 14:33:56 RHEL-8-Salt-Master kernel: traps: smbclient[4026317] trap invalid opcode ip:7f4d2928b78a sp:7ffdb5362480 error:0 in libgnutls.so.30.28.2[7f4d29146000+1dd000]
Mar 01 14:33:56 RHEL-8-Salt-Master systemd-coredump[4026339]: Resource limits disable core dumping for process 4026317 (smbclient).
Mar 01 14:33:56 RHEL-8-Salt-Master systemd-coredump[4026339]: Process 4026317 (smbclient) of user 0 dumped core.
Mar 01 14:38:33 RHEL-8-Salt-Master kernel: traps: smbclient[4027642] trap invalid opcode ip:7fadcdf3278a sp:7ffe81095480 error:0 in libgnutls.so.30.28.2[7fadcdded000+1dd000]
Mar 01 14:38:33 RHEL-8-Salt-Master systemd-coredump[4027658]: Resource limits disable core dumping for process 4027642 (smbclient).
Mar 01 14:38:33 RHEL-8-Salt-Master systemd-coredump[4027658]: Process 4027642 (smbclient) of user 0 dumped core.
```

Comment: how did you install  libgnutls.so.30.28.2?

Comment: you might want to enable the actual coredumping and look at the backtrace of where in libgnutls that trap actually happened, what called the function with which argument and so on. Coredumps are powerful debugging tools!

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. I didn't manually install libgnutls, it must have been pulled in along with samba-client...?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I don't know how to use coredumps. I was hoping someone else has seen this before as it seems fairly common. I'm just trying to SMB to Windows Server 2019.

Comment: I don't know, but it certainly didn't look that common; this being a serious bug I would have expected it to be fixed upstream. Where else did you see it?

Comment: Nowhere else, only in RHEL 8